# How to get the selected value of some random dropdown in Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, drop-down-menu

```
<select ng-model="myModel" id="searchAsset" class="search">    
         <option ng-repeat="asset in assettype" ng-click="assetclick()" value="{{asset}}"></option>
</select>

<select class="search" id="searchLevel">
    <option class="chooseLevel" ng-repeat="level in levellist" value="{{level}}"></option>
</select>
```

While performing some logic on second dropdown, I want to fetch the selected value of the first dropdown or vice-versa. How can I do this?
I tried using `$("#searchLevel").value` and `$("#searchLevel option:selected").text()`

Answer (score 0):

The direct answer to this question is to use the [`.val()`](https://api.jquery.com/val/) method for jQuery like so:

```
var selectedVal = $("#searchLevel").val();
```

However, the slightly less direct, but true answer is that you should not be doing anything like this in an angular app - changes in the dom should only be affecting your view model.

Answer (score 0):

When your using angular, jquery is really not required.

As per your code, The first select menu value will be stored in the `ng-model` attribute value i.e. `myModel`.

In your second select menu, specific the `ng-model` as well. You can just fetch the value of the drop down menu by calling `ng-model` name.

```
<select class="search" id="searchLevel" ng-model="secondSelect">
    <option class="chooseLevel" ng-repeat="level in levellist" value="{{level}}"></option>
</select>
```

For example,

If you want to access the value inside your controller on change event, then

```
$scope.changeEventhandlerForFirstSelect = function() {
  //    $scope.myModel will contain the value
}
```

Similarly, for second select menu `$scope.secondSelect` will give that value.

Answer (score 0):

try

$("#searchLevel").val();

with: $("#searchLevel option:selected").text() you get the text not the value.